# What does "insane" mean when referring to an exciting development?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> “It’s an exciting development. I did not know that they were coming out with not one but two of these [quantum computing results] in the same week,” says Scott Aaronson, a theoretical computer scientist at the University of Texas at Austin. “**That's pretty insane**.”
>
> Source: Scientific American
> [China Is Pulling Ahead in Global Quantum Race, New Studies Suggest](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/china-is-pulling-ahead-in-global-quantum-race-new-studies-suggest/)

Does "That's pretty insane" mean "That's pretty amazing"? Or does it mean "That's pretty foolish"?  The former is informal while the latter is formal (normal sense of "insane"). I am not sure.

Comment: To be clear, "that's pretty insane" by itself *can* either be meant in a positive way (amazing) or a negative way (foolish). It's the *additional context* of the paragraph that should leads you to conclude the former, not something inherent in the phrase.

Comment: French (*délirant,* probably *fou*) and German (*irre, verrückt*) have similar uses.

Comment: No one can explain it better than Cypress Hill: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RijB8wnJCN0

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The sense is *surprising*, in a positive way. That can be seen in the first sentence:

> It’s an exciting development.

[Merriam-Webster *insane*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insane)

> 4 **informal** :
> **also : exceptionally good or impressive**
> *Minnesota … has blazed out to an insane start, taking an early lead in the Northwest Division.*

Comment: +1, but I think that Merriam's definition could be improved by adding the additional qualifier of *exceptionally good or impressive* to a degree that makes it *almost* **unbelievable** or **incredible**.  The implication being that, if you didn't know better, you might have to almost be insane to believe that such an amazing thing just happened.

Comment: I think the emphasis is not that it is surprising so much as it is extraordinary to the degree of unbelievable (which would be a stand-in). Of course everything extraordinary is by implication surprising, but that's not the focus.

Answer (score 2):

It's closest in meaning to "pretty amazing" :

> *4. **exceptionally good or impressive*** ([Merriam-Webster, 4](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insane))

The other definitions don't fit because they all have negative meanings, and in this context, where China is moving ahead of the US in an important field, it doesn't make sense to call China or anybody in the story "crazy".